# How to get log file details in FuseBAI

Tags: java

I am new to fuse source and i am trying to implement FuseBAI with help of ReadMe.md document in url https://github.com/fabric8io/fabric8/blob/master/bai/ReadMe.md.

i have done the configuration what they mentioned in org.fusesource.bai.agent.cfg.my configuration file is

```
    # Fuse BAI configuration
# ======================
#
# This is only used if the bai feature is installed.
# see: http://fuse.fusesource.org/eip/bai.html
#
bai.xml = simpleconfig.xml
bai.xml = simpleconfig.xml
```

and my simpleconfig.xml is

```
<policySet xmlns="http://fuse.fusesource.org/schema/bai">
<policy id="nonAuditContexts" to="direct:testfusebai">
<contexts>
<exclude>
<context bundle="*" name="audit*"/>
</exclude>
</contexts>
<endpoints>
<include>
<endpoint>file:*</endpoint>
</include>
</endpoints>
<events>
<exclude>
<event eventType="FAILURE_HANDLED"/>
</exclude>
</events>   
</policy>
</policySet>
```

both file location is /opt/FuseESBEnterprise-7.1.0/etc
and spring.xml is

```
<camel:camelContext id="camel-A">
<camel:route>
<camel:from uri="direct:audit" />
<camel:to uri="file:/home/xyz/working_dir/order1" />
</camel:route>
</camel:camelContext>
```

when i deploy this i am getting the following information in console

```
 .fuse-047 | Instrumenting camel context camel-context.xml.277-camel-A with audit notifiers
2014-01-29 09:56:15,484 | INFO  | ExtenderThread-2 | DefaultAuditPolicy               | ?                                   ? | 275 - org.fusesource.bai.bai-core - 7.1.0.fuse-047 | Updating AuditEventNotifier Auditor(bundle: camel-context.xml camelContextId: camel-A) to policySet: PolicySet([Policy(nonAuditContexts, to: direct:testfusebai, Contexts(exclude[ContextFilter(*:audit*)]), Endpoints(include[EndpointFilter(file:*)]), Events(exclude[EventFilter(FAILURE_HANDLED)]))])
2014-01-29 09:56:15,485 | INFO  | ExtenderThread-2 | NotifierRegistration             | ?                                   ? | 275 - org.fusesource.bai.bai-core - 7.1.0.fuse-047 | Starting notifier Auditor(bundle: camel-context.xml camelContextId: camel-A)
2014-01-29 09:56:15,490 | INFO  | ExtenderThread-2 | OsgiBundleXmlApplicationContext  | ?                                   ? | 106 - org.springframework.context - 3.0.7.RELEASE | Not publishing application context OSGi service for bundle null (camel-context.xml)
2014-01-29 09:56:15,499 | INFO  | ExtenderThread-2 | ContextLoaderListener            | ?
```

But as per policyset configuration it is not creating the log file. How can i get the log file using FuseBAI.

Answer (score 0):

I've not used BAI but let me give this a shot. It looks like you're trying to send your audit messages to `direct:testfusebai` and not to a file. Try something like this: `file:///tmp/testfusebai&Append=true`